# PHP monolog error while signin with google

Tags: php, monolog

I updated api client with composer and now i get this error while logging in with google

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "Level" in /***/***/***/***/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Level.php on line 32
```

This is line 32:

```
enum Level: int
```

What caused this error?

You can see the file [here](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/src/Monolog/Level.php)

Comment: What php version are u using? Enums are added with php version 8.1.

Comment: PHP Enumerations weren't available until 8.1.

Comment: If you ran composer update and got code that differs from the runtime environment, you might check the version where you ran it (e.g., cli is 8.1 but website is 8.0 or 7.4). I had this issue when Composer's official docker image stopped supporting 7.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @stefket suggested, Enums are introducted [with php 8.1](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/enums)

The minimum supported **PHP version** of the latest release of Monolog [is also **8.1.0**](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/releases/tag/3.0.0-RC1)

You can either upgrade your php version or use the `2.5.0` release compatible with PHP 7.2

`composer require monolog/monolog:2.5.0`